# How to overlay a dropdown menu over its parent ( or specific element ) in HTML?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use a dropdown menu that allows user to check information if the mouse pointer is on the menu. If the user removes the pointer then the dropdown menu will disappear. Everything is in the table.

The problem I have now is, in the very end row, the part of a dropdown menu looks hidden ( to more precisely describe, it looks underneath of other element ).

[image]

The image should be preferred being over everything ( I hope so ). I tried to touch z-index but it doesn't work.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover">
<tbody>
<td>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn dropdown-toggle" style=" background-color:#EF4836;color:white; margin:2.5px 0;" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="true">
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:300px;">
    <span style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"><font color="#ffffff">Hi!<br></font></span>
      <li>Hello Stack Overflow</li>
        <li>
          Google vs Amazon</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</td>
...
```

The below is the computed CSS property of the drowndown menu in Chrome.

```
background-color: rgb(239, 72, 54);
background-image: none;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
cursor: pointer;
direction: ltr;
display: block;
filter: none;
float: left;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 34px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-bottom: 2.5px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 2.5px;
outline-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
padding-left: 14px;
padding-right: 14px;
padding-top: 7px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: none;
touch-action: manipulation;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 115.438px
```

The below is the computed property of .

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
direction: ltr;
display: table-cell;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 173px;
line-height: 18.5714px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-top: 8px;
vertical-align: top;
width: 328px;
```

Where do I need to see to solve this issue? Please let me know! (: Looking forward to receiving good advice from experts!

Best

Comment: Its kind of unclear as to what you are looking for here. Do you have an example somewhere?

Comment: What values did you set `z-index` to?